# Are node title & body instances update-able through the field API?

Tags: entities

I'm guessing it's not possible, since what works on other instances won't for the title & body. (Trying to adjust widget weight.)

```
  $core_instances = array(
    // array(
    //   'field_name' => 'title',
    //   'entity_type' => 'node',
    //   'bundle' => 'article',
    //   'weight' => 1,
    // ),
    // array(
    //   'field_name' => 'body',
    //   'entity_type' => 'node',
    //   'bundle' => 'article',
    //   'weight' => 4,
    // ),
    array(
      'field_name' => 'field_tags',
      'entity_type' => 'node',
      'bundle' => 'article',
      'weight' => 7,
    ),
    array(
      'field_name' => 'field_image',
      'entity_type' => 'node',
      'bundle' => 'article',
      'weight' => 6,
    ),
  );

  foreach ($core_instances as $instance) {
  $instance_info = field_info_instance($instance['entity_type'], $instance['field_name'], $instance['bundle']);
  $instance_info['widget']['weight'] = $instance['weight'];
  field_update_instance($instance_info);
  }
```

If I uncomment the title & body instances, I get the following error:

> FieldException: Attempt to update an instance of a nonexistent field . in         [error]
>   field_update_instance()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Title is not a field unless you're using the [Title](https://drupal.org/project/title) module.
That's why your first call doesn't work.

Body should work, unless you've deleted the field (can you see it on admin/structure/types/manage/article/fields?)

Comment: Thanks, you're right about body, I assumed it was something about them both. For my purposes, being able to adjust body is enough, since I can weight the fields around it.